# how to delete dynamic created textbox controls on dropdownlist selectedIndexChanged event and recreate new dynamic control on new selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    Aspx page:

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:placeholder id="container" runat="server" visible="false"></asp:placeholder>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


On Code Behind file:

 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
generateDynamicControls();
}

 private void generateDynamicControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            HtmlGenericControl td1 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "lbl" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString();
            lbl.Text = dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString() + " :";
            lbl.Width = new Unit(170);
            lbl.Style.Add("padding-left", "10px");
            lbl.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
            td1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            tr.Controls.Add(td1);

            HtmlGenericControl td2 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.ID = "txt" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString();
            txtBox.CssClass = "TxtBox";
            txtBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            txtBox.Width = new Unit(840);
            td2.Style.Add("colspan", "3");
            td2.Controls.Add(txtBox);
            tr.Controls.Add(td2);
            container.Controls.Add(tr);

            HtmlGenericControl tr1 = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
            HtmlGenericControl td3 = new HtmlGenericControl("td");

            td3.Style.Add("colspan", "4");
            td3.InnerHtml = "&nbsp;";
            tr1.Controls.Add(td3);
            container.Controls.Add(tr1);

            //container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

            //LiteralControl literalBreak = new LiteralControl();
            //literalBreak.Text ="</br>";

        }
        container.Visible = true;
    }
}

`dt(datatable)` is filled from other function.
```

this is working fine and controls are created correclty.

But I want to recreate this dynamic controls on selected change event of dropdownlist. but before recreate these controls i have to delete previously created controls.

I have tried below code in dropdownlist selected changed event to delete these controls and recreate new controls.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        container.Controls.Remove(container.FindControl(dt.Rows[i]["nSubjectId"].ToString()));
                    }

generateDynamicControls();
```

But it's not work and give me following error. becuase of onload event is alread ycalled first and created the dyanmic controls.

Multiple controls with the same ID '*lblOrals*' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

How can I solve this problem.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Give the for loop variable (i) to your label id, like the below way

```
lbl.ID = "lbl" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString()
 +i.ToString();//i is loop variable for coordinated with labelid.
```

Now if the `"dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"]"` is return `"LabeleName"`, When the for loop will assign the values like 
`dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString() + i.ToString()` , So It is return values like `"LabeleName1"`

Finally you got the label id's are followings name

```
lblLabeleName1
lblLabeleName2
lblLabeleName3
.
.
.
.etc
```

textbox are like

```
txtBox.ID = "txt" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString() + i.ToString();
```

Result are

```
   txtLabeleName1
   txtLabeleName2
   txtLabeleName3
.
.
.

etc.
```

Remove fields code like

```
 //For label 

    container.Controls.Remove(container.FindControl("lbl" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString() +i.ToString()));

//For TextBox

 container.Controls.Remove("txt" + dt.Rows[i]["sSubjectName"].ToString()+ i.ToString() ));
```

**And Should  call the generateDynamicControls(); method inside of !ISPostBack() event in page load event**

Like

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
  if(!IsPostBack)
     {
  generateDynamicControls();

     }
   }
```

Comment: I have to use same id of label and textbox in entire page. because i am storing the value of this dynamic created textbox into table.

Comment: he he !! Don't worry simply add the for loop variable in end side for label, and add the for loop variable in front side for text box :)

Comment: how? could you please show me the example or write some code here?

Comment: If I add loop variable before and/or after label and textbox. but on recreate the control on dropdownlist selectedchanged event it will again create the same controls with same ids. because onload event is called before selectedchange event is call.

Comment: hmm call the generateDynamicControls(); method inside of !ISPostBack() event in page load event

Comment: Please see onemore time my answer

Comment: I was implementing according to your suggestion.

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
  if(!IsPostBack)
     {
  generateDynamicControls();

     }
   } 

And its work perfeclty.

Thanks a lot Ramesh Rajendran.

Comment: I just use if(!IsPostBack) in OnLoad event and regenerate controls from dropdownlist selectedchange event.